# Controller creates empty Object from fetch/Json object

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm an sending data to the MVC controller using vanilla JS fetch, the payload of the request looks fine, but there data does not reach the controller. How can I fix this?

```
fetch(
    '/InvoiceIncoming/SaveCsvInvoiceToDb', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
    body: csvRows[j] // JSON.stringify(csvRows[j]) does also not work
})
    .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        return response.json();
    }) //returns an object called response
    .then(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }).catch(function (err) {
        console.warn('Did not work', err);
    });
```

The controller looks like this:

```
   public ActionResult SaveCsvInvoiceToDb(ImportInvoiceIncoming csvInvInc)
   {          
       return Json("ok");
   }
```

The payload of the request looks like this

```
{
   "ConstructionSite":null,
   "InvoiceIncoming":null,
   "CsvAmountGross":"70,73",
   "AmountGross":0,
   "CostCenterNumber":"H0040000",
   "CsvDueDate":"06.09.2023",
   "DueDate":"2023-09-06T02:00:00+02:00",
   "InvoiceDatevId":"5B86985A-9EC9-DEF9-665C-72ED614E07BA",
   "CsvInvoiceDate":"07.08.2023",
   "CsvVatKey":"94",
   "InvoiceDate":"2023-08-07T02:00:00+02:00",
   "InvoiceNumber":"E01000GNRF",
   "Paid":null,
   "SupplierName":"supplierino",
   "SupplierVatId":"numberino",
   "Supplier":null,
   "Vat":{
      "DUssId":1,
      "OUmsatzsteuersatz":0,
      "DGueltigVon":"2011-12-24T00:00:00",
      "DGueltigBis":"9999-12-31T00:00:00",
      "DAngelegtAm":"2011-12-24T10:00:26.897",
      "DAngelegtVonFk":-2,
      "DLetzteAenderungAm":"2011-12-24T10:00:26.897",
      "DLetzteAenderungVonFk":-2,
      "VatRateText":"0,00"
   },
   "HasConvertedDueDate":true,
   "HasConvertedInvoiceDate":true,
   "HasConvertedAmountGross":false,
   "HasValidVatRate":true,
   "CostCenterMatches":false,
   "DateMatches":false,
   "AmountGrossMatches":false,
   "SelectedForImport":true
}
```

But the controller shows the following values for `csvInvInc`:

```
?csvInvInc
{ImportInvoiceIncoming}
    AmountGross: 0
    AmountGrossMatches: false
    ConstructionSite: null
    CostCenterMatches: false
    CostCenterNumber: null
    CsvAmountGross: null
    CsvDueDate: null
    CsvInvoiceDate: null
    CsvVatKey: null
    DateMatches: false
    DueDate: {01.01.0001 00:00:00}
    HasConvertedAmountGross: false
    HasConvertedDueDate: false
    HasConvertedInvoiceDate: false
    HasValidVatRate: false
    InvoiceDate: {01.01.0001 00:00:00}
    InvoiceDatevId: null
    InvoiceIncoming: null
    InvoiceNumber: null
    Paid: null
    SelectedForImport: false
    Supplier: null
    SupplierName: null
    SupplierVatId: null
    Vat: null
    amountGross: 0
    csvDueDate: null
    csvInvoiceDate: null
    cu: {de-DE}
```

Comment: This could be caused by a variety of reason, the first of which comes to mind could be JSON serializer settings. Try to use a simple tool like [cURL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL) to post a simplified HTTP request and see if that works. If it does, the problem is with the JavaScript; if it doesn't, it's with the server-side code. Try to simplify the payload to just a few properties and see if you can still reproduce the problem, then post a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: when posting json be sure to use "FromBody" attribute to bind to your model: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api#using-frombody

Comment: I forgot to mention, when I add [FromBody], the app crashes

Answer (score 0):

To pass complex data to the server always make sure to serialize and deserialize your data. In your JavaScript Code make changes to the following line i.e.

Replace

```
csvRows[j]
```

With

```
JSON.stringify(csvRows[j])
```

Now, since this is a complex string, therefore your controller signature should look something like below i.e.

Replace

```
   public ActionResult SaveCsvInvoiceToDb(ImportInvoiceIncoming csvInvInc)
   {          
      return Json("ok");
   }
```

With

```
   public ActionResult SaveCsvInvoiceToDb(string csvInvInc)
   {   
       ImportInvoiceIncoming data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ImportInvoiceIncoming>(csvInvInc.ToString()) 

       return Json("ok");
   }
```

This will capture your data properly.

Comment: As you can see in the comment `body: csvRows[j] // JSON.stringify(csvRows[j]) does also not work`

Comment: the reason you are getting the data like this it that you are sending and receiving object not string and remember JSON is a string base packaging. So apply the string at both sending and receiving end as already mentioned in my post.